# Find all values of $z=\ln(\sqrt{3}+I)$ where $|z|<6$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to find all the values of the following:
$$z=\ln(\sqrt{3}+i), \quad |z|<6$$
I understand that is all the values that found inside the circle $|z|<6$
what I did so far :
If $\zeta = \sqrt{3}+i$, then
$$\ln(\zeta)=\ln|\zeta|+i(\operatorname{Arg}(\zeta)+2 \pi k), \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

1. $\operatorname{Arg}(\zeta)=\pi$?
2. $k={0,1,2,3,4,5}$?

any advice?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually $\sqrt{3}+i$ has argument $\pi/6$, thus all logarithms of that number form the set 
$$\left\{\ln 2+i (\pi/6+2\pi k):k \in \mathbb Z \right\} .$$
Since we are interested only in the logarithms within the disk $|z|<6$ alone only certain values of $k$ are allowed. i.e. those who satisfy $$\sqrt{\ln^2 2+(\pi/6+2 \pi k)^2}<6 .$$

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks

Comment: I need to check $-1,-2\cdots $ aswell right?

Comment: @OfirAttia: that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $\operatorname{Arg}(\sqrt{3} + i) = \pi/6$ (basic trig). Since $\sqrt{\sqrt{3}^2 + 1^2} = 2$, $|\zeta| = 2$. Lastly, for which values of $k$, $|z| \geq 6$? Exclude those values.

Hint: Plug in the first few values of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$1.$  The right triangle having legs with length $\sqrt 3$ and $1$ has hypotenuse of length $x$.  What is $x$?  What angle occurs between the hypotenuse and the longer of the two legs?

$2.$  If $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ when $z=x+iy$ then

$$\left|\ln|\sqrt 3+i|+i(\arg(\sqrt 3+i)+2k\pi)\right|=?$$